# Adding just one parameter of class in the db ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I display all lines in the db represented by the model Client

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.etat)
     @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.decision)
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
 } 
 </td>
}
```

And I want to edit only the parameter decision for all lines (instances) of clients and then send them to fill only this parameter for every clients with an input type submit. The problem is that I only know how to add the whole object client :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Client client)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.Clients.Add(client);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return View(client);
}
```

I am so confused because of Ienumerate there is an error, so maybe I have to use a list ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the List objet as action parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Ienumerable<Client> clients)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach(var client in clients)
        {  
           db.Clients.Add(client);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(client);
}
```

Normally it will works, I hope it may helps you.

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't recognize Ienumerable. I try to add it at the top but nothing. Also an other question do I have to let the later create method to fill first all the parameters and then add the new create method for adding the decision param for all instances of Client Thank you very much